# Android database directory on emulator

Tags: android, database, directory, emulation

**Hello i created a database class on andorid that below.**

```
public class Veritabani extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String Veritabani_Adi = "Veritabanim";
    private static final int Veritabani_Version = 1;
    public Veritabani(Context context) {
    super(context, Veritabani_Adi, null, Veritabani_Version);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE ARKTABLE (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , ad TEXT, soyad TEXT);");  
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST OperatorTablosu");
    onCreate(db);
    }
}


**then i declare may Veritabani class in my activity as below.**

public class DictionaryActivity extends Activity {
    Spinner spnLanguage;
    Veritabani objdb;;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dictionary);
        spnLanguage=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spnLanguage);
        objdb=new Veritabani(this);
        spinnerfill();

    }
```

i don't have an exception on logcate or console. 
But when i look may data/data/myappp/        i dont see database directory.

i used android 2.2 version

Answer (score 0):

check In the **DDMS** perspective if you are using Eclipse. there you can easily find whether your database is created or not.

Answer (score 0):

you want to **DDBMS**

1. Go to **mnt/sdcard/yourdatabase name**.it's database store in sdcard
2. internal memory means **data/yourpackagename/yourdatabasename**